# How to hide dropdown on load jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

Good Day,

I'm trying to understand how JQuery hide/ show and change elements work.  In the example is 4 dropdowns with the change function on the first drop down 'Please Select'.  Based on the option chosen the correct box appears.  Looks good there.  The only trouble I'm having is how to hide all but the parent box onload.

**Fiddle**:   https://jsfiddle.net/wj_fiddle_playground/mt69f5w4/15/

Javascript Below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#exampleFruit').change(function() {
    var val = $('#exampleFruit').val();
    $('.exampleSubselect').hide();
    if(val) {
        $('#example'+val).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery methods works simple:

`show()` just adding css-property `display: block`

`hide()` just adding css-propery `display: none`

So you should just add `style="display: none;"` to your selects

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/kodxg0y8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Show Hide Elements</title>

</head>
<body>
<tr id="table1">
 <select id="exampleFruit">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
</select>
</tr>

<tr id="table2">
<select id="exampleApple" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
    <option>Red Delicious</option>
    <option>Granny Smith</option>
    <option>Cox's Orange Pippin</option>
</select>
</tr>
<tr id="table3">
<select id="exampleBanana" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
    <option>Plantain</option>
    <option>Burro</option>
    <option>Cavendish</option>
</select>
</tr>
<tr id="table4">
<select id="exampleOrange" class="exampleSubselect" style="display: none;">
    <option>Blood</option>
    <option>Navel</option>
    <option>Valencia</option>
</select>
</tr>
</body>
</html>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#exampleFruit').change(function() {
        var val = $('#exampleFruit').val();
        $('.exampleSubselect').hide();
        if(val) {
            $('#example'+val).show();
        }
        
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok that makes since I will try option value now